# Add multiple jdks in path of .bashrc file on ubuntu

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, path

I am installing java 8 and java 11 on my linux machine which has ubuntu 20.04 installed.
Since the command `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk` gives the following error:

> 403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
> Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libcommons-io-java all 2.11.0-2 [297 kB]
> Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libmaven-resolver-java all 1.4.2-3build1 [555 kB]
> Fetched 9,419 kB in 42s (226 kB/s)
> E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.18%2b10-0ubuntu1%7e22.04_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

So, I installed it by downloading the JDK package from Oracle and then manually creating /usr/java and setting path manually.

This was okay when I had one java version. Now, if I install another how do I add it with the path in .bashrc file?
My .bashrc file looks like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/java/jdk1.8.0_351/
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_351/bin"
```

I was trying to install maven that required installing jdk 11.
Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Why do you think you will gain from having multiple JDKs in your path?  The *best* case is that the one appearing earliest is always used, but if that one happened to be missing some tools then you might effectively have a mixture of tools from different JDKs.  You can have multiple JDKs, but they should not all be in your path.

Comment: You might have a look at [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com) or [sdkman](https://sdkman.io) for managing multiple java versions.

Comment: Maven does not require JDK 11. Java 8 should work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't intend to have multiple jdks in same path but I should be able to switch between java versions. Since I am not able to access the alternatives option which comes when we install by sudo apt-get

Comment: @rebel_codeaz, clearly, you already know how to set up your shell configuration to configure a JDK.  I don't see what prevents you from changing that to support a different JDK, or changing it back when you want the first.  Thus, if having two configured at the same time is not your objective, then I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: However, @rebel_codeaz, the alternatives system can be used with software from any source.  You seem to be used to software installed from DEBs doing the setup for you (which indeed can be an advantage of installing from packages) but you can use the alternatives CLI to do the same yourself.  Consult [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives).